# Question about the proof of Theorem 2.39 of Niven's book of Number Theorem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-explanation

In Page 102 of Niven's book ***An Introduction of the Theory of Numbers*** (5th edition), there is a Theorem 2.39:

**Theorem 2.39** If $p$ is a prime then there exists $\phi(\phi(p^2))=(p-1)\phi(p-1)$ primitive roots modulo $p^2.$

But I have trouble in understanding the last sentence of the first paragraph of the proof. For convenience, I quote it below:

*Proof*   $\quad$ We show that if $g$ is a primitive root $\pmod p$ then $g+tp$ is a primitive root $\pmod {p^2}$ for exactly $p-1$ values of $t \pmod p.$  Let $h$ denote the order of $g+tp\pmod{p^2}.$ (Thus $h$ may depend on $t.$) Since $(g+tp)^h\equiv 1\pmod{p^2},$ it follows that $(g+tp)^h\equiv 1\pmod{p},$ which in turn implies that $g^h\equiv 1\pmod{p},$ and hence that $(p-1)\mid h.$ On the other hand, by Corollary 2.32 we know that $h\mid \phi(p^2)=p(p-1).$ Thus $h=p-1$ or $h=p(p-1).$ In the latter case $g+tp$ is a primitive root $\pmod{p^2},$ and in the former case it is not. We prove that the former case arises for only one of the $p$ possible values of $t.$  Let $f(x)=x^{p-1}-1.$ In the former case, $g+tp$ is a solution of the congruence $f(x)\equiv 0\pmod{p^2}$ lying above $g\pmod{p}.$ Since $g'(g)=(p-1)g^{p-2}\not\equiv 0\pmod{p},$ we know from Hensel's lemma (Theorem 2.23) that $g\pmod{p}$ lifts to a unique solution $g+tp\pmod{p^2}.$ For all other values of $t\pmod{p},$ the number $g+tp$ is a primitive root $\pmod{p^2}.$

The rest part of the proof is omitted.

My question is: Why "For all other values of $t\pmod{p},$ the number $g+tp$ is a primitive root $\pmod{p^2}$"? I know the order $h$ modulo $p^2$ of $p$ depends on $t.$ But the functional relationship between $t$ and $h$ is unknow (maybe we can not depict it analytically), so
why there is just one $t$ such that $g+tp$ is not a primitive root $\pmod{p^2},$ while the other values of $t$ correspond to primitive roots modulo $p^2?$ Can anyone explain in detail?

Comment: That's what it proves, read the proof again : it lifts to a **unique solution** for $t$

Comment: To obtain a proof of the theorem it suffices to prove the existence of 
 at least one primitive root modulo $p^2,$ because that  implies that multiplication modulo $p^2$ on the members of $\{1,.., p^2-1\}$ that are not divisible by $p$ is a cyclic group with $\phi(p^2)$ members. .. And a finite cyclic group with $n$ members has $\phi (n$) generators.